# Is it possible to redirect HTML to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div class="action-button">
    <a href="/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1&amp;redirect=http://blabla.com" class="MyButton">Hello
    </a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to call a javascript function (stored in a file) while redirecting instead of redirecting to a specific URL ?

The javascript file is in the same domain as the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: Why down voting ? What's wrong with someone not expert asking basic question ??

Comment: Yes, if you have a server-side javascript such as [node.js](http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs) or others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a query string. for example

```
 <a href="http://blabla.com/mypage.html?callfunction=1">Hello</a>
```

then on the page it redirects to (mypage.html) you'd do something like

```
<script>
if (getParameterByName('callfunction') == 1)
    callMyFunction1();
</script>
```

You could also pass parameters via querystrings.

For more info on querystrings see--
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: Actually the first part of the code is important. Because it opens a session using facebook credentials (<a href="/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1&amp;redirect...) once it's done, is it possible to redirect to a specific function stored in the same domain ? Thanks

Comment: why not redirect to a client side html first and then make your ajax call to your server. but if you must go server first you could still extract a querystring from it and then run it in client code. if you're the server you're building the client code.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the function needs a context to run in. That would be a website. Although you could create a dummy page that does nothing but execute the function you're interested in using.

Answer (score 0):

Include the JavaScript upfront, then call the function from the submit handler

Comment: can you provide a syntax of the redirection please ?